# SharePoint on premise health endpoint?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, performance, health-analyzer

Third party apps often use sharepoint 2010/2013/2016 web services. This might add some strain on the sharepoint farm if they are too aggressive.

These third party apps, if responsible, will check the health of sharepoint before/during/after running to see how healthy sharepoint is.

I know there is something called the SharePoint "health analyzer" that can do this...

But is there a SharePoint api (rest or soap) that can provide health statistics for a SharePoint farm that third party apps can utilize ?

I'm just looking for statistics that relate to load of the server. So CPU usage, memory usage and network utilization statistics. I am looking in from a third party application perspective and where I am making lots of HTTP requests through a CSOM application and I want to make sure I'm not hurting the health of the SharePoint instance with all my HTTP requests.

Comment: Please state exactly what type of information you're looking for. There is no specific endpoint for 'health', but 'health' means very different things to different people.

Comment: Your question isn't SharePoint-specific at this point. You'd be better served posting in ServerFault - https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: OK I can appreciate that. But SharePoint itself may very well have an API endpoint that provides these server statistics, right?

Comment: No, hence why you're looking for a server level management product. SharePoint does not replicate the functionality of perfmon, SCOM, and other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am looking for Server-level management statistics, and as per comment from Trevor above, SharePoint does not replicate the functionality of perfmon, SCOM, and other tools.

Therefore there is no api for this in SharePoint and I should seek Server-level management apis if available, a question better suited for serverfault.com.